# Longest Common Palindromic Subtring

Tags: algorithm, substring, palindrome, memoization

Does anyone know how to do this algorithm top-down with memoization?
My first intuition was to reduce this problem to Longest Common Substring, but check each substring and see if it's a palindrome. I just can't figure out how to do this recursively. Can someone please help me out?

```
Problem Statement #

Given two strings ‘s1’ and ‘s2’, find the length of the longest palindromic
substring which is common in both the strings.

Example 1:

Input: s1 = "fbdbaccf"
       s2 = "tbdbaccf"
Output: 3
Explanation: The longest common substring is "bdb".

Example 2:

Input: s1 = "abcdefghimississippi"
       s2 = "abcdefghiississi"
Output: 7
Explanation: The longest common substring is "ississi".
```

Comment: Here is an unconventional, hackish approach that justifies a comment at best. Suppose the two strings are the ones in your first example. As I understand we wish to find the longest common substring in the array `[ 'fbdbaccf', 'fccabdbf', 'tbdbaccf', 'fccabdbt']`, where the second (fourth) string is the reverse of the first (third) string. Suppose we join these strings with three distinct characters not in the strings as separators: `'fbdbaccf:fccabdbf;tbdbaccf,fccabdbt'`...

Comment: ...Now see if the string is matched by the regular expression `([^:]{3})(?=[^:]*:[^;]*\1[^;]*;[^,]*\1[^,]*,.*\1)`. This is seen to match `'bdb'` beginning with the second character of the string. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SAQhP1/1). We therefore have found a three-character string that appears in all four of the joined substrings, so the longest such string has at least three characters...

Comment: ...We note that both original substrings have eight characters. We therefore could begin by attempting to match the regular expression with `{3}` changed to `{8}`. If there were a match (an eight-character string would be matched) the two original strings must be equal and be palendrones, but we'd be finished. That  would in fact fail so we would change `{8}` to `{7}`, try again, and so on, until we found the three-character string `'bdb'` that passed the test and we'd be done. To understand the regular expression hover the cursor over each part of it at the link to obtain an explanation.